# Wrong endian with wstring_convert

Tags: c++11, encoding, endianness, codecvt

I recently discovered the `<codecvt>` header, so I wanted to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

I use the `codecvt_utf8_utf16` facet with `wstring_convert` from C++11.
The issue I have, is when I try to convert an UTF-16 string to UTF-8, then in UTF-16 again, the endianness changes.

For this code :

```
#include <codecvt>  
#include <string>  
#include <locale>  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>
                                                convert;

  u16string utf16 = u"\ub098\ub294\ud0dc\uc624";

  cout << hex << "UTF-16\n\n";
  for (char16_t c : utf16)
    cout << "[" << c << "] ";

  string utf8 = convert.to_bytes(utf16);

  cout << "\n\nUTF-16 to UTF-8\n\n";
  for (unsigned char c : utf8)
    cout << "[" << int(c) << "] ";
  cout << "\n\nConverting back to UTF-16\n\n";

  utf16 = convert.from_bytes(utf8);

  for (char16_t c : utf16)
    cout << "[" << c << "] ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

I get this output :

> UTF-16
>
> [b098] [b294] [d0dc] [c624]
>
> UTF-16 to UTF-8
>
> [eb] [82] [98] [eb] [8a] [94] [ed] [83] [9c] [ec] [98] [a4]
>
> Converting back to UTF-16
>
> [98b0] [94b2] [dcd0] [24c6]

When I change the third template argument of `wstring_convert` to `std::little_endian`, the bytes are reversed.

What did I miss ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5599be701f3ebb32

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's weird, i'm using gcc 5, I will try to compile it from sources tonight, to see if I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Switching compiler to gcc also doesn't reproduce this on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbac3e56d8f55c30

Comment: Well, it works on OS X and Windows, so I guess there is a problem with libstdc++, I will report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a bug, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66855
It will be fixed in 5.3